# Unterschied "gesamt" vs "ganz"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Was ist der **genaue** Unterschied zwischen "gesamt" und "ganz"?

Beispiel:

> Ich brauche die **ganze** Applikation.

> Ich brauche die **gesamte** Applikation.

Für mich haben diese beide Wörter im obigen Beispiel die gleiche Bedeutung und keines *tönt* falsch.

Bei diesem Beispiel ist es jedoch klar, dass es **ganzen** und nicht **gesamten** ist:

> Ich esse den **ganzen** Kuchen.

> <s>Ich esse den **gesamten** Kuchen</s>

Wie ist die Regel definiert? Hat es mit etwas zählbarem zu tun? **Ganzen** nur wenn man die Anzahl kennt?

Comment: Ich würde sagen "entire" vs. "whole". Aber möglicherweise ist mein Wissen über die Semantik im Englischen auf falsch.

Comment: Wörter *tönen* nicht. Das tun nur Dinge, die einen Ton ausstoßen. Zudem ist nicht klar, was *Applikation* sein soll. Eine Verabreichung, zum Beispiel eines Medikaments? Eine Anwendung im Sinne einer kosmetischen Behandlung? Ein Softwareprodukt? Einen Sticker, den man auf Kleidung aufnähen kann? ...

Answer (score 1):

"Ich esse den gesamten Kuchen." ist sprachlich völlig korrekt. Hier ist nicht ein einzelner Kuchen, sondern Kuchen als nicht zählbare Kategorie gemeint.

"ein ganzer Kuchen" == ein kompletter Laib Kuchen

"der gesamte Kuchen" == die komplette Menge an Kuchen (z.B. in einer Bäckerei)

Schwierig wird es, weil umgangssprachlich "ganz" und "gesamt" häufig synonym verwendet werden.

Das erste Beispiel ist ohne Kontext unverständlich. Ich vermute, es geht um Software? Dann würde ich "vollständig" oder "komplett" verwenden, oder besser noch näher spezifizieren (z.B. "einschließlich Treiber und Bibliotheken").